# My line manager is holding me back

Tags: company-culture

I work in middle management, where my line manager often makes me do:

- strategic work, reporting, process improvement for him

but does not give me the flexibility to properly own my work.

If whilst doing the work, I talk to people above him to get the relevant information, he has a tendency to feel undermined and then starts to micromanage.
 He also has a tendency to take my work, take credit for it and use it as a means to build his own profile.

I am wondering if this is common in Corporates given it is the first time working in one?

I am also feeling as though I am being held back in my own career, from feeling as though I am not being properly recognized for my contributions.

Comment: When you say his own profile, do you mean within the company or LinkedIn etc.?

Comment: Within the company for promotions - he has used a lot more of the work I have done in presentations.

Comment: Has your manager received any promotions based off of your work?  If not, why do you expect that you should?

Comment: @sf02 yes he has, not only my work but others too.

Answer (score 3):

> I work in middle management, where my line manager often makes me do:
>
> strategic work, reporting, process improvement for him but does not
>   give me the flexibility to properly own my work.
>
> If whilst doing the work, I talk to people above him to get the
>   relevant information, he has a tendency to feel undermined and then
>   starts to micromanage. He also has a tendency to take my work, take
>   credit for it and use it as a means to build his own profile.
>
> I am wondering if this is common in Corporates given it is the first
>   time working in one?

It's not exactly clear what you mean by "Corporates" here.

But in my career, I haven't worked for a manager who tended to feel undermined and started to micromanage.

All managers I've worked for took credit for the work of their team to the extent that they should have. It's their team - if good things happen they get to claim some credit.

Answer (score -1):

Do the people you talk that is above him know that he is taking credit for your work? Maybe you know his boss and can discuss it with him? Have you tried to contact hr about it?

I can understand from your boss's position of being undermined especially if you haven't tried to glean that info from him first so maybe you are wrong. You might want to take a step back and let him get a bit more control while you try and sort this out. Open up some communication with your manager and find out if you are in the wrong first before you start thinking the manager is wrong.

Comment: In this instance, it was an informal chat I had with his boss and I was given very good feedback to improve the proposal. There was a mutual understanding with his boss that this was just a proposal and that is it. I feel that my line manager has over reacted personally.

Comment: That is probably why he acting up if what you say is true. Unless his behaviour is threatening there isn't much you can do. Just wait for the rug to be pulled from underneath him. Keep your head down and do you duties and you will be fine. If it bothers you and you still want to do something then mention it to his boss but prepared to find a different job if it goes south. After all he is your manager at the moment and unless he is failing in his duties he can turn it back around on you.

Comment: Yeah, agree that is probably why, but I literally can't do my job properly if I can't interact with the right people. Going through him all of the time is very slow.

Comment: That is his issue, if the productivity goes down then it is going to show. His job is to make you productive and if you are doing all you can then you aren't at fault. Do this for a couple of weeks and if you get puled by hr for your lack of productivity then explain the situation, what you did before and what you do now because of your boss's micromanagement, it should turn in your favour. If you are applying to new places now then this may be the best option. Keep in touch with his boss on good terms as well and he may ask the reason why you are falling behind and chase up on it.

Comment: However the productivity may not change anything, and no one might mind the speed. If so then you would have to just deal with it or move on to a different company

Answer (score -2):

You can try to keep him from feeling undermined by CC him on the emails to people to people outside your department.  You'll also want mention his name and the specific work that you were tasked with so the other person knows *why* you are asking.

If you speak with them in person, send your boss a summary (what, who, when, project name) with a CC to the person you spoke with so that person can confirm or clarify any of the information you attribute to them (keeps a nice record also).

I cannot tell from the question if you are expecting more credit than you should be expecting.
To put it another way: when your boss tasks you to do certain strategic work *he should* get the credit for tasking you to do it.  He told you to do it after all.

Comment: He shouold get the credit for "tasking" you to do it but that is not the same as taking all the credit for it...

Comment: @SolarMike exactly that. He will present it as his own at meetings with key Stakeholders, getting promotions from it whilst I am currently stagnating.

Comment: @bobo2000 I had someone take my work a few times - I then got a stooge to ask detailed questions about how to implement xyz - sadly they could not answer : mouth flapping like a fish... The management soon got to realize who did what.

Comment: @SolarMike Again, I cannot tell **from the question** if OP is expecting too much credit.  A promotion for strategic work the manager has someone do, will not necessarily *directly* benefit the person that did the work. If OP said that OP proposed and was given permission to do the strategic work, that would be different.

Comment: @SolarMike I am actively applying for other roles because of this sort of behavior to be honest. My line manager is reluctant to promote me questioning the value I bring to the org, despite directly benefiting from it.

Comment: @bobo2000 best of luck in your search and hope you get a better manager as well... A decent manager could well say " I asked Fred to write a code to do xyz and this is what he came up with"... Or I tasked the team to do xyz and this is the result...

Comment: @SolarMike "sadly they could not answer : mouth flapping like a fish" - great example of stealing work. If s/he had said, "Great question, when it comes to that level of detail I'll have to refer you to Mike." that would have been totally different, right?

Comment: @SolarMike is this sort of behaviour common in the corporate world?

Comment: @bobo2000 there are all types of managers...

Comment: @J.ChrisCompton It depends how they started the presentation... If they said "I did this..." then even deferring to someone else tends to give the game away...

Comment: @SolarMike he presents it as his own. It is annoying me to be honest, because I have had at times people questioning the value I bring to the company from simply not knowing what I am doing with that not being communicated.

Comment: @bobo2000 Given that, just get out from under him.  He will rise with that strategy, but he's building a house of cards and it will likely fall out from under him.  He should, for example, be telling people what you are working on because if they question you then they are also questioning his manager abilities. Doubt this occurs to him based on what you're saying because he is so eager for credit.